# How to send error message once a http call takes more time than is required in Spring integration dsl?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

Here I've three subflows and out of which one is HTTP outbound call. I want that HTTP call should try to get response till a mentioned time. If times out then the main flow should break and it should show a Error message in Json format as output.

Below is the code -

```
     @Bean
      public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return flow ->
            flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
                .split()
                .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                .scatterGather(
                    scatterer ->
                        scatterer
                            .applySequence(true)
                            .recipientFlow(flow1())
                            .recipientFlow(
                                f ->
                                    f.gateway(
                                        flow2(), gateway -> gateway.replyTimeout(3000L).errorChannel("errorChannel")))
                            .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                    gatherer ->
                        gatherer
                            .releaseLockBeforeSend(true)
                            .releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() == 2))
                .aggregate(someMethod1())
                .to(someMethod2());
      }

  private IntegrationFlow returnError() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel").handle(System.out::println).get();
  }
```

I've added the errorChannel but how do I send a customized message to the user?

Answer (score 1):

See documentation for error handling in the messaging gateway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-no-response.

Consider to add an `errorChannel()` along side with that `replyTimeout()` on the gateway definition to build an error reply you'd like. However you also may consider to add something like a request timeout for the `RestTemplate` you use for that HTTP call to prevent the long wait for HTTP response.

**UPDATE**

First of all you need to understand that request-reply is a bit of block-n-then-wait approach. We send a request and if the process consuming that message is blocking - performed immediately in a thread producing the message, then we don't reach "wait" part until that process lets go. In most cases (by default) a `DirectChannel` is used, so it is blocked because it is performed in the calling thread. This process might be your HTTP call which is also request-response pattern. So, we don't reach that "wait" part until this HTTP call returns, or timeout, or fail with error. Only after that a `replyTimeout` takes its effect to wait for the reply from the underlying process. This can be changes if an input channel of that process is not direct. See an `ExecutorChannel` or `QueueChannel`. This way a sending part exits immediately because there is nothing to block it and it goes to the "wait" part to observe a `CountDownLatch`.

So, you need to think again if that `replyTimeout()` option is appropriate for your or not. Perhaps the mentioned `requestTimeout` for the `RestTemplate` is better option for you, than rework your flow to the async solution to leverage that `replyTimeout()` feature. Again: see the documentation I've mentioned about that `replyTimeout` feature.

The error handling is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling.

It is really not recommended to rely on the global `errorChannel` bean. This is one which is used everywhere in async processes where there is no an explicit error channel configured.

You said in your question "send a customized message to the user", but your error handling flow is one-way - `System.out::println`. If you want to return anything from the error handling flow, the endpoint must be replying one, e.g.:

```
.handle((p, h) -> "The error during HTTP call: " + p)
```

Also see if you declare that `returnError()` correctly. It really cannot be just plain `private` method. The `IntegrationFlow` must be declared as a bean this or other way to initiate wiring process for endpoints and channels. Right now that one is just a plain, unused `private` method. The framework does not see that method to do anything. See basics of the Java DSL in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl

Comment: Can you please tell me how to configure the error channel so that it returns an exception in json format? one example would help.

Comment: Hi @Artem,Kindly see the edited post, where I've added the errorChannel but not getting how to return a response from there to the user.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hi @Artem, if I want to use Rest template way then how do I embed that with Spring integration here (HTTP OUTBOUND GATEWAY)?

Comment: Not sure why is the question. The `Http` factory has this overload `outboundGateway(String uri, RestTemplate restTemplate)`